# Java\Groovy - java.io.IOException: Authentication failure in simple authenticated HTTP request

Tags: java, http, authentication, groovy

I'm using Groovy\Java. I'm trying to download a file from a server with a simple HTTP GET. This code works on every computer we tried, except for my coworker's computer.

```
new File(fullFilePath).withOutputStream { out ->

            url = new URL(COMPLETE_URL).openConnection() 

            Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
                            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                return new PasswordAuthentication (USER, PASSWORD);
                            }
                        });

                out << url.inputStream
            }
```

The strange thing is that this code works perfectly on my computer and on an AWS instance, on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012, and it DOES NOT work on my coworker's computer, on Windows 10. All 64bit.

We all have the same Java version. Antivirus and Firewall are disabled. I tried with his credentials and he tried with mine, it still doesn't work only from his computer.

Error:

```
java.io.IOException: Authentication failure
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1695)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
...
```

What else could we try and check?

Comment: Have you tried to call `Authenticator.setDefault` before `openConnection`?

Comment: @Mene thank you but that didn't work. I also tried with a purely Java version and it still doesn't work on his computer while it works on mine. I took it from: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/ReadingURLsProtectedwithHTTPAuthentication.htm

Answer (score 0):

Using `Authenticator.setDefault()` is a bad approach for this. It will cause Java to send your username and password on ANY request the JVM makes which requests credentials.

Why this is failing only on one machine is hard to tell, but likely the Java configuration must be different.

In any case, try changing your code to just set the authentication header on each request. That will make your code less reliant on Java's internals and will not just send your credentials on each request the JVM might make in the future:

```
def authHeaderValue = 'Basic ' + Base64.encoder.encodeToString("$USER:$PASSWORD".bytes)

new File(fullFilePath).withOutputStream { out ->
    connection = new URL(COMPLETE_URL).openConnection()
    connection.setRequestProperty('Authorization', authHeaderValue)
    out << connection.inputStream
}
```

I wrote a [blog post](https://sites.google.com/a/athaydes.com/renato-athaydes/code/groovy---rest-client-without-using-libraries) about making HTTP requests in Groovy without libraries, you may want to check it out.